# Typeahead Widget advanced Yii2

Tags: yii2, bootstrap-typeahead

I'm trying to create live search from my controller with this widget.

```
ActiveForm::begin([
    'action' => Url::to(['product/search']),
    'id' => 'main-search-form',
    ]) ?>

<?php //echo Html::input('text', 'search') ?>
<?php echo Typeahead::widget([
     'name' => 'search',
     'options' => ['placeholder' => 'Search...'],
     'scrollable' => true,
     'pluginOptions' => ['highlight'=>true],
     'dataset' => [
                      [
                      'remote' => [ 
                           'url' => Url::to(['product/searchlist']) . '?search=%query'
                            ],
                      'limit' => 10
                      ]
                  ]
            ]);
```

This is my answer from product/searchlist:

```
[{"product_name":"Garant"},{"product_name":"Garant"},{"product_name":"Garant"},{"product_name":"pay 8"},{"product_name":"pay 8"},{"product_name":"pay 8"},{"product_name":"pay1"},{"product_name":"pay1"},{"product_name":"pay1"},{"product_name":"pay1dd"},{"product_name":"pay1dd"},{"product_name":"pay1dd"},{"product_name":"pay1jjj fixed"},{"product_name":"pay6"},{"product_name":"pay6"},{"product_name":"pay6"}]
```

And when I type in searchbox something it shows me:

```
{"_query":"{\"product_name\":\"Garant\"}","product_name":"Garant"}
```

kind of fields in dropdown

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking. See the [ask] page for help clarifying this question.